# Execute after FOR loop with FS action

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, fs-extra

I have a for loop that calls an action fs.copy after. After that for loop is complete I need to execute a command. I think I need to do a callback once the for is complete. The issue that I think I'm running into is the fs.copy is run async so the for loop actually completes before the fs.copy action does. Suggestions?

```
var sessionNumeber = 7;
photoOrder = (An array of photo names);
for(var i = photoOrder.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log('Moving Photo');
    fs.copy(cfg.watchedFolder+photoOrder[i]+'.jpg', cfg.outputFolder+sessionNumber+"/"+i+'.jpg', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // i.e. file already exists or can't write to directory 
            throw err;
        }
    });
});
nextCommand();
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Code has been updated

Comment: add counter for photos, when it will be equal to length of array  - invoke your function

Comment: No, that's not valid js.

Comment: @loadaverage Do have an example of how to do that. I tried to add one inside the fs.copy call back, but could not get it to work.

Comment: @Oleander it is with the exception of the photoOrder array which I didn't list.

Comment: Something like https://jsfiddle.net/tL0qt8sk/

Comment: You could use `copySync()` if your files are small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `for` loop is not async but `copy` is, so you cannot use `for` to loop throught async function. Solution is using `async` library.

https://github.com/caolan/async

> async.map(arr, iteratee, [callback])

For example, you can try it:

```
async.map(photoOrder, function (photo, callback) {
    console.log('Moving Photo');
    fs.copy(cfg.watchedFolder + photo + '.jpg', cfg.outputFolder + sessionNumber + "/" + i + '.jpg', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // i.e. file already exists or can't write to directory 
            callback(err);
        }
    });
}, function (err, results) {

    nextCommand();
});
```

Comment: Its seems to be running nextCommand(); after each iteration instead of after the everything is completed.  Thoughts?

Comment: No, last function run when all is completed. More information : https://github.com/caolan/async#map

Comment: Ahh its looks like a typo in your code missing "})" before "},function(err, results){" If you want to fix it  I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing typo. I just updated. Did you try it?

Comment: I try and it runs once fine. But if I try and run it a 2nd time, nextCommand is not run. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does i come from? And you have to callback even if there is no err.

Comment: @ShanShan thats what was missing. I was not calling the callback every time.